# nltk.tokenize executing properly from Shell but getting error as a script file

Tags: python, nltk

I use python idle 3.5.1 in mac os 10.11.4
i am executing the following code directly in python shell and it works perfectly

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> sample_sentence = "Hi, this is a sample sentence. Python is great"
>>> sample_sentence
'Hi, this is a sample sentence. Python is great'
>>> sent_tokenize(sample_sentence)
['Hi, this is a sample sentence.', 'Python is great']
>>>
```

but i am saving the same code as a script file and when i execute 
i am getting an error.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
sample_sentence = "Hi, this is a sample sentence. Python is great"
print(sent_tokenize(sample_sentence))
```

when i run this script file i am getting the following error

> RESTART: /Users/Documents/sample_codes/python3_sample.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/Documents/sample_codes/python3_sample.py", line 2, in 
>   from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize ImportError: No
>   module named 'nltk.tokenize'; 'nltk' is not a package

I don't understand this. Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663762/tokenizer-errors-with-nltk

Comment: These too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592238/nltk-no-module-named-corpus and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would happen if you would name your python script `nltk.py` - rename your script.

Comment: in my case file name is not nltk.py, but python3_sample.py. But i renamed it to some generic name. Still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @SanthoshSrinivasan okay, before I remove the answer. Could you check if you have `nltk.py` somewhere in your project or elsewhere on the python path?

Comment: sir, thanks it helped . I had an old file with nltk.py and nltk.pyc in the same directory. I deleted both and it worked fine.